# gSOAP: How to compare two value-structs (with JSON-content) in C?

Tags: c, json, gsoap

I´m using gSOAP (in C) for a client application, which is calling a Java-webservice. I´m using the function `json_call()`.
I have a request-struct filled with the JSON-input-data and I get a response-struct filled with the JSON-output-data from the Java-service. Both JSONs have the same structure in general, but can have more, less or changed elements.

My task now is to find out, in which elements the response is different from the request. The main-element is a large array with a lot of members, like:

```
{
    "objects": [
    {
        "@id": "OBJ00001",
        "name": "value",
        ...
    },
    {
        "@id": "OBJ00002",
        "number": 123,
        ...
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

I can identify any object of the same kind with the `@id` field.

It´s simple to iterate the `objects` array with something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < has_size(value_at(response, "objects")); i++)
```

But then I´missing a function, which can compare members ("objects") with the same `@id` in request and response. Something like "findMemberWithSameField" and then "equal" (**which both does not exist!**):

```
struct member *currentMemberInResponse = NULL;
struct member *memberWithSameField     = NULL;

for(i = 0; i < has_size(value_at(response, "objects")); i++)
{
    /* get the current member out of the response array */
    currentMemberInResponse = nth_value(value_at(response, "objects"), i);

    /* Find member/object with same @id in request */
    memberWithSameField = findMemberWithSameField(value_at(request, "objects"), currentMemberInResponse , "@id"));

    /* equal is true if all fields are the same */
    if(equal(currentMemberInResponse, memberWithSameField))
    {
        /* Do nothing, because nothing changed */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

Any idea on that task? Otherwise I have to do write my own "findMemberWithSameField" and "euqal".

Kind regards Daniel

Comment: Here have a look at https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON it has jSON patch support

Answer (score 0):

The JSON C++ API defines `operator==` to compare two objects recursively. The latest version 2.8.55 works (I've tested) to compare two JSON objects, where `operator==` calls the following function:

```
bool json_eqv(const value& x, const value& y)
{
  ...
  switch (x.__type)
  {
    ...
    case SOAP_TYPE__struct:
      if (x.size() != y.size())
        return false;
      else
      {
        const _struct& s = x;
        const _struct& t = y;
        for (_struct::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        {
          _struct::iterator j;
          for (j = t.begin(); j != t.end(); ++j)
            if (!strcmp(i.name(), j.name()))
              break;
          if (j == t.end() || *i != *j)
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
```

This can be rewritten to C with something like:

```
int json_eqv(const value *x, const value *y)
{
  if (x->__type != y->__type &&
      (x->__type != SOAP_TYPE__i4 || y->__type != SOAP_TYPE__int) &&
      (x->__type != SOAP_TYPE__int || y->__type != SOAP_TYPE__i4))
    return false;
  switch (x->__type)
  {
    case SOAP_TYPE__boolean:
    case SOAP_TYPE__i4:
    case SOAP_TYPE__int:
      return int_of(x) == int_of(y);
    case SOAP_TYPE__double:
      return double_of(x) == double_of(y);
    case SOAP_TYPE__string:
    case SOAP_TYPE__dateTime_DOTiso8601:
      return !strcmp(string_of(x), string_of(y));
    case SOAP_TYPE__struct:
      if (has_size(x) != has_size(y))
        return 0;
      else
      {
        size_t i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < has_size(x); ++i)
        {
          for (j = 0; j < has_size(y); ++j)
            if (!strcmp(nth_member(x, i), nth_member(y, j))
              break;
          if (j == has_size(y) || !json_eqv(nth_value(x, i), nth_value(y, j))
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
      }
    case SOAP_TYPE__array:
      if (has_size(x) != has_size(y))
        return 0;
      else
      {
        int i;
        for (i = 0 ; i < has_size(x); ++i)
          if (!json_eqv(nth_nth(x, i), nth_nth(y, i))
            return 0;
        return 1;
      }
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```